# SearchView in fragment (non in toolbar) can't remove underline

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

In my fragment I use searchView (not in toolbar).
My layout snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:queryHint="Some hint"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my fragment's code :

```
        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchCatalogSuggestionsAdapter(getActivity()));
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

As you can see I try

```
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

But underline is not help.
Here screenshot:

[image: Search-view-underline]

Comment: Try setting background as null for the `searchview `(works in case of `AutoCompleteTextView`).

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar SearchView is actually a LinearLayout and the background is set on an EditText inside it, so that won't work.

Comment: android:background="@null"  - not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCompat supplies two styles for the SearchView:

- the default with underline
- one for use in the Action Bar without underline

You can change the style like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar"/>
```

The style looks like this:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar"/>

<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="defaultQueryHint">@string/abc_search_hint</item>
</style>
```

You could use the attributes directly, of course.